# I am having problems using ifndef.. I get and error: error undefined reference

Tags: c++

I am using a classes with inheritance. My student . h works perfectly when called by itself, however when I use it as a base class I get these errors:

```
/tmp/ccSCMNjf.o:umain.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'student::showStudent()'
/tmp/ccSCMNjf.o:umain.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'student::showStudent()'
/tmp/ccSCMNjf.o:umain.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'student::showStudent()'
/tmp/ccSCMNjf.o:umain.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'student::showStudent()'
/tmp/ccl9pOYI.o:underGradImp.cpp:function underGrad::underGrad(std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char,  std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, double, double, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, sStat): error: undefined reference to 'student::student(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> , std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, double, double)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using header guards, and I have also tried using #pragma once with the same results.

If I take out the header guards I get this error:

```
In file inlcluded from underGrad.h:160,
                  from umain.cpp:9:
student.h:19:7: error: redefinition of  'class student'
student.h:19:7  previous definition of 'class student'
```

here is the student.h file

```
#ifndef H_student
#define H_student

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class student 
{

public:

  student(string = "", string = "", string = "", string = "", double = 0.0, double = 0.0, double = 0.0);

  string getLastName() const;

  string getFirstName() const;

  string getID() const;

  void getCharges(double&, double&) const;

  double getBalance() const;

  string getMajor() const;

  double getGPA() const;

  void setName(string, string);

  void setID(string);

  void setMajor(string);

  void setCharges(double, double);

  void setGPA(double);

  void showStudent();

private:

  bool checkID(string) const;

  string expandMajorCode(string);

  string lastName, firstName, studentID, major;

  double gpa, charges, financialAid, balance;

  static const double MAX_CHARGES = 10000.0;

  static const double MAX_GPA = 4.0;

};

#endif
```

---

and here is my underGrad.h file which is using student.h as a base class

---

```
#ifndef H_underGrad
#define H_underGrad

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "student.h"


using namespace std;

enum sStat {PROBATION, GOOD, SPECIAL, NONE};

class underGrad : public student {

public:
  underGrad(string = "", string = "", string = "", string = "", double = 0.0, double =         0.0, double = 0.0, string = "", sStat  = NONE);
  string getAdvisor() const;
  sStat getStatus() const;
  void setAdvisor(string);
  void setStatus(sStat);
  void showStudent();

private:
  string advisor;
  sStat sStatus;

};

#endif
```

---

there is also a main that includes students.h 
and underGrads . h but aside from those calls it is not important.
I have included student . h as is in an implementation file and it works perfectly
so I am thinking there is either something wrong with my second class definition
or the includes somehow. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
NOTE:
The errors are produced for every member of student - not just showStudent
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your problems are nothing to do with `#ifndef`, they are link errors. Where have you _defined_ `student::showStudent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Keep the include guards.
2. Make sure you link the file that implements `student` (`student.cpp`?) into your executable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize I wasn't using the studentImp.cpp